# Adding items to a list that won't change when new items are added

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a simple input bar where one types a new item to be added to a list. However, when I add a new item it replaces the preceding added data and updates the list as normal.

The function used to add a planet is as follows: (.service)

```
addPlanet(planet: Planet) {
    if(planet.name && planet.description) {
    this.planets.push(planet);
    }
  }
```

in the component it is as follows:

```
newPlanet: Planet = {} as Planet;

addPlanet(): void {
    this.planetService.addPlanet(this.newPlanet)
  }
```

the html looks as follow:

```
<h1>Create a Planet</h1>
<input [(ngModel)]="newPlanet.name" type="text" placeholder="new name...">
<input [(ngModel)]="newPlanet.description" type="text" placeholder="new desription here...">
<button type="button" (click)="addPlanet(newPlanet)">Create</button>
<h1>Planet Listings</h1>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor = "let planet of planets"><b>{{planet.name}}:</b> {{planet.description}}<button type="button" class="ml-2" (click)="removePlanet(planet)">X</button></li>
</ul>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: You'll need to use an Observable in your service, and subsribe it in your component to detect changes.

Comment: how are you initializing `planets` in service

Comment: @Sujay... I got an array within service as follows:

Comment: planets: PLanet[] = [ {name: 'the planet name', description: 'whatever the planet is about'} ];

Answer (score 0):

Check this StackBlitz: [List of planets](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9pgthh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

HTML file:

```
<h1>Create a Planet</h1>
<input [(ngModel)]="name" type="text" placeholder="new name...">
<input [(ngModel)]="description" type="text" placeholder="new desription here...">
<button type="button" (click)="addPlanet(name, description)">Create</button>
<h1>Planet Listings</h1>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor = "let planet of planets"><b>{{planet.name}}:</b> {{planet.description}}</li>
</ul>
```

TS file:

```
interface Planet {
  name: string,
  description: string
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  planets: Planet[] = [];
  name: string;
  description: string;

  addPlanet(name, description) {
    let planet: Planet = {
      name: name,
      description: description,
    } as Planet;

    if(planet.name && planet.description) {
      this.planets.push(planet);
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that in your `[(ngModel)]` directive you are binding the last object inserted in the array directly (newPlanet).

Comment: I inserted my array of planets within my service file. All I needed to add was a refresh of the addPlanet functionality within my onInit(). Your method is great as well, thanks for the feedback.